Azure Event Grid Partner Topic Not Showing Up
According to the MS documentation, partner topics are supposed to be automatically created when you create a partner configuration. I did that for graph and nothing appears in partner topics. I also can't create a graph partner topic. Not sure what the issue is. When I click create button for graph API, I don't have the ability to save it. The two buttons I see are event grid documentation and view pending partner topics. What is going on?

Could you include more details like what documentation you are following and Portal images too?

The Partner Topic for Microsoft Graph API is created automatically once you create a subscription.
The steps should be:

Create Partner Configuration for the Event Grid
Add Partner Authorization - MicrosoftGraphAPI
Create a subscription and specify name of the topic by sending a request to the Graph API

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
    "changeType": "Updated,Deleted,Created",
    "notificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=<azure-subscription-id>&resourcegroup=<resource_group_name>&partnertopic=yourPartnerTopic&location=germanywestcentral",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=<azure-subscription-id>&resourcegroup=<resource_group_name>&partnertopic=yourPartnerTopic&location=germanywestcentral",
    "resource": "users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2024-10-12T00:00:00Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}


In Azure Portal, search for Event Grid Partner Topics



Click on the Partner Topic



Activate Partner Topic

Once the Partner Topic is active, you can create an event subscription



Thank you for the response. I got stuck on POST info. Where do I perform that? Can I do that portion from logic apps, graph explorer, or does it matter? And once I do that, the topic is created, correct? And when I send the post, do I need to send the same data with it? And just so I'm tracking, do I send this data:     "notificationUrl": "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=&resourcegroup=<resource_group_name>&partnertopic=yourPartnerTopic&location=germanywestcentral" but with my info correct? Is the clientState the registration ID?

It doesn't matter from what you create a subscription. Once the subscription is created, it will automatically create the topic which will appear under Event Grid Partner Topics in Azure Portal. clientState is optional and can be omitted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-graph-api-events?context=graph%2Fcontext&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#how-to-create-a-microsoft-graph-api-subscription

I was able to create a subscription and the topic appeared. Thank you
